# How to set maximum number of compiler warnings allowed in MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on a project with multiple developers and have noticed an increase in compiler warnings. Some of the warnings are very old and very difficult to clear so we have learned to turn a blind eye to them, however new warnings are unacceptable.

I am looking for a way to stop the increase of compiler warnings without first having to address the warnings we have grown accustomed to, so I am looking for a way to set a hard limit on the number of warnings generated before the build process fails in order to force developers to rethink their solutions when it introduces new warnings.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There will never be a better time to address old warnings than now. If they are truly difficult to fix wrap them in `#pragma warning disable/default` for the time being. You won't lose them because that's easy to search for. Once you have zero warnings turn on warnings as errors and be happy. As long as you have warnings you accept you'll never be able to successfully sell a zero tolerance policy.

Comment: If you have a team that ignores warnings, whoever is in charge of your project should be actively looking for a new development team.

Comment: @RetiredNinja We are "actively" working on clearing the warnings but we are trying to ensure the number stops growing in the meanwhile. Some of the projects throwing warnings are maintained by other groups or are considered stable and we can not touch it.

Comment: **Suppress warnings for individual files** (or lower the global warning level for that file). The IDE lets you do this by right-clicking on a file, or you can add `#pragma`s in your code. That way, you can suppress warnings for files that you are not going to modify now, but you can still have warnings turned all the way up for *new* code. There's no way to set a "maximum" number of warnings, and this wouldn't be a sensible way to go, even if there were a way to do it.